# Grouping Similar Strings Together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

We have a data dilemma involving our products and how they're setup in our ERP system.

When a product is revised, we end up creating a new part number and change the name slightly.

Here is how it shows up

```
Name                                 QtySold
Product 1                            10      
Product 1 V2                         08
Product 1 V3                         06
Product 1 V3 With Accessories        12
```

All of these product names vary in length, otherwise I'd use the LEFT() function to group them together.

How can I write a query that will take anything that is obviously related (by the naked eye) and group and summarize them together?

The ideal output would be something like this:

```
Name         QtySold
Product 1    36
```

Comment: How do *you* know when the product name ends and the version name begins? Though seems like what you really need to do is fix your design.

Comment: It's not your naked eye which is doing the grouping, it's your brain.  Unfortunately, your brain knows a lot more about how things should be grouped than we possibly can.  For instance, in your example above, we have no way to tell if those four lines should be one group ('Product 1*') or three ('Product 1', 'Product 1 V2*', 'Product 1 V3*') or four groups.  You will need to give us more explicit rules than this.

Comment: Can you modify how the products are related in the ERP system? One way would be to have some type of parent product or base product and then have these be related to that (a self referencing table). Not sure how flexible the ERP system is but changing the structure / schema would be the best approach.

Comment: The future plan is to get these grouped as a parent/child inside the ERP, but right now we need a solution until that gets implemented. We're running on 15 years of "this is how we've always done it" and it's starting to effect data quality.

Comment: *"right now we need a solution until that gets implemented"* so explain how you know where the end of the product name is. Saying "obviously it's `Product 1`" won't help, that *isn't* obvious to the RDBMS. If you don't have a clear and defined way of knowing where the product name ends, and the versioning name starts, the RDBMS has literally no chance.

Comment: For example, are ***all*** the product names in the format `{Single Word Name} {Integer}`? If so, we can work with that. Or would it be `{Multiple Word, non numerical, Name} {Integer}`? We can work with that too. But `{Name with has no conformity} ({Maybe a number, maybe not}) ({Versioning})` won't help.

Comment: {Multiple Word, non numerical, Name} {Integer} is most likely what we're looking at. Here's a real world example of what it looks like:

 - BRUSH MOWER 72
 - BRUSH MOWER 72 V2
 - BRUSH MOWER 72 V3
 - BRUSH MOWER 72 V3 LF

Comment: so the version number is always found at or near the end of the name with the pattern V9? And the maximum number of numerals in that pattern is what? 1, 2, more? If you searched for a pattern like '% V[0-9]%' that might find the starting location of your version number?

Comment: If the pattern is always {Base name} + {version suffix}, you can match the version suffix and strip it off, for instance: `LEFT(ProductName, PATINDEX('%V[1-9]', ProductName) - 1)`